# ComputerCraft: custom printer software

Tags: module, lua, minecraft, computercraft

I'm trying to make a custom printing program for ComputerCraft, that can make more copies by one command and I have a problem. Every time a put a file into it, it doesn't break lines and puts `?` where the line break is (`\n`). How do I do it correctly?

Problem should be somewhere here:

```
for i=1,copyNumber do
    printer.newPage();
    printer.setPageTitle(pageLabel);
    local h = fs.open(filePath, "r");
    local text = h.readAll();
    print("Tisknu:");
    write(text.."\n");
    printer.write(text);
    h.close();
    printer.endPage();
end
```

Comment: Probably, you should set new cursor position using `printer.setCursorPos(1,line_no)` before writing text into new line.

Comment: You are opening the file in text mode, then reading it into a buffer in one operation. That produces a buffer with lines separated by `\n` characters. If your printer needs CRLF sequences as line endings, then you should prefer to read the file a line at a time and inserting the correct line endings as required, or manipulate a printer cursor as mentioned by Egor. I don't do Minecraft and can only speak to the Lua edge of things otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i=1,copyNumber do
    printer.newPage();
    printer.setPageTitle(pageLabel);
    local h = fs.open(filePath, "r");
    local text = h.readLine(); --Read one line
    while(text != nil) --If line isn't nill
        printer.write(text); --Write the line
        _,y = printer.getCursorPos() --Get the current cursor pos.
        printer.setCursorPos(1,y+1); --Move one line down
        text = h.readLine(); --Read the next line
    end
    h.close(); --Close the file
    printer.endPage(); --End the page
end
```